# Normalize a vector differently than normal

Tags: math, greatest-common-divisor

I have a vector that represents the change between one vector and another. The vectors are always diagonal to each other. For example, if the first vector was `(1, 0)` and the second was`(3, 2)`, the change is `(2, 2)`, which should be normalized to `(1, 1)`. "Normal" normalizing by dividing both X and Y with the vector's length results in about 2.83 for the example vector which is not what I need. How can I achieve this "normalization"?

Comment: What is the rule for this *abnormal* normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both components of your vector by their [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: This works otherwise fine but if my change is, for example, `(-2, -2)`, the normalized is still `(1, 1)` as it should be `(-1, -1)`

Comment: Then divide by `abs(gcd(x, y))` instead of `gcd(x, y)`.